# Disable Buttons while animating a Uivew which is subview of main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I am trying to do Passcode lock app programtically in IOS which is provided default in IOS in Settings -> Genral -> Passcode Lock

When I enter Password for the first time it will ask to  reenter the password for that i am animating a sub-view which is present above the keypad… While animating i want all the buttons to be disable…. And the keypad present  is created one by using buttons not the default keyboard provided by IOS when tapped on textField,,, Please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the user interaction before animating, reenable after the animation

```
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                   animations:^{
                     // Animation
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                   }];
```

Comment: In the above case I am appending the label of button by appending it to a Mutable string i want to disable the button after the length of string is equal to 4 and then immediately after no time I again want the user interaction enabled.. I am confused with the process..Please help me out –

Answer (score 0):

Well, to disable a button you do the following:

```
[button setEnable:NO]
```

I think what you are trying to do is disable the button while something is animating, so you should try this

```
[button setEnable:NO];

[UIView animateWithDuration:timeOfAnimation 
animations:^
{
    //insert animation here
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    [button setEnable:YES];
}];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: And i have another doubt… In the above case I am appending the label of button by appending it to a Mutable string i want to disable the button after the length of string is equal to 4 and then immediately after no time I again want the user interaction enabled.. I am confused with the process..Please help me out

Comment: Im not sure but, if you want to just disable, then enable the button after no time, just do it normally. Use [button setEnable:YES]; then [button setEnable:NO];. If this isn`t what you meant, please specify better.